# Using UIWebView displaying certain PDFs renders some text incorrectly

Tags: iphone, pdf, uiwebview

Occasionally, when loading a PDF (using a UIWebView), parts of the text will appeared 'garbled'.  If you zoom in or out on the pdf, the text will change its 'garbledness'.

This occurs on multipage pdfs with images and texts and seems to only happen on certain pieces of text, but the font doesnt seem to be the issue as the next line or somewhere else with the same font will work fine.

Another thing, we noticed this on iPad, as well as an iPhone 3g (running 3.1.3) however it doesnt seem to be the case on the simulator (running 4.0.1), or another 3gs running 4.0.1.

So my question is this: Has anyone else encountered this? or heard of this being a known issue with Apple? Does anyone know if it is a particular font to avoid when creating the PDFs? (not ideal since the app can load any pdf, but since this is a pdf that comes with the app would still be semi-useful)

Note: this is not the visual artifacts as described in another post on SO (where rotating a PDF in a UIWebView would "tear" the page), this is only distortion on some of the text in the pdf.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please file a bug (http://bugreport.apple.com/) and attach the PDF that is causing issues.